# Can you explain what is new Minor(); in this code?

Tags: java

Is `new Minor();` in main function creating an object or is it something related to constructor? (I am new to Java so I didn't understand this example)

```java
class Uber {
    static int y = 2;

    Uber(int x) {
        this();
        y = y * 2;
    }

    Uber() {
        y++;
    }
}
```

```java
class Minor extends Uber {
    Minor() {
        super(y);
        y = y + 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Minor();
        System.out.println(y);

    }
}
```

Comment: The example makes no sense whatsoever. What exactly are you trying to achieve and more importantly, what book are you trying to learn Java from?!

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens:

1. `new Minor()` constructs an object of the Minor class and calls the ctor of the Uber class in the `super(y)` statement.
2. `this()` increments `y` by 1, so y becomes 3 (take a look at the default ctor)
3. then the next line overwrites it to 3*2 which is 6
4. finally `y += 3` makes `y` 6

---

Please tell me if you need any more clarification

Comment: `new Minor()` doesn't create an object of the `Uber` class, it constructs one of the `Minor` class, which is a subclass of `Uber`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yep, typo. Thanks for bringing that to my attention

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you understand the java constructor execution order well, it is very easy to tell the output is `9`.

You add more print to understand the execution order like this:

```
class Uber {
    static int y = 2;

    Uber(int x) {
        this();
        y = y * 2;
        System.out.println("after uber#this: "+ y);
    }

    Uber() {
        y++;
        System.out.println("after uber#default: "+ y);
    }
}

class Minor extends Uber {
    Minor() {
        super(y);
        y = y + 3;
        System.out.println("after super: "+ y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main: "+ y);
        new Minor();
        System.out.println(y);

    }
}
```

Which will print like this:

```
main: 2
after uber#default: 3
after uber#this: 6
after super: 9
9
```

Comment: This seems to explain the result of code, but doesn't answer the question asked _"Is new Minor(); in main function creating an object or is it something related to constructor?"_

Answer (score -1):

`new Minor()` just creates a new instance of the `Minor` class, by calling its default (i.e. no-argument) constructor. That instance is just thrown away, since there's no assignment statement. It doesn't seem to be useful code at all, though.

Comment: Take a careful look. That "useless and discarded instance" modifies y before being thrown away

Comment: Totally wrong, consider `y` is a static field of  `Uber`.